# Defining a function on KnockoutJS ViewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In KnockoutJs, I have the following ViewModel for an Admin page I'm working on:

```
function UsersViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.roles = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.post('http://localhost:23926/admin/acl/getroles',
        function(data) {
            const availableRoles = $.map(data,
                function(role) {
                    return new Role(role);
                });
            self.roles(availableRoles);
        },
        'json');

    $.post('http://localhost:23926/admin/acl/getuserroles',
        function(data) {
            const usersWithRoles = $.map(data,
                function(userWithRole) {
                    return new User(userWithRole);
                });
            self.users(usersWithRoles);
        },
        'json');

    self.selectedUser = ko.observable(self.users[0]);

    // operations
    self.setCurrentUser = function (user) {
        self.selectedUser(user);
    }

    self.SelectedUserHasRoles = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.selectedUser().roles().length > 0;
    });
}
```

And in my HTML, I have the following:

```
<div class="col-md-6" data-bind="if: $root.SelectedUserHasRoles()">
  <h4><i class="fa fa-shield" aria-hidden="true"></i> Roles</h4>
  <hr />
  <div id="roles-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: $root.selectedUser().roles">
      <div class="role-token" data-bind="text: name"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I think that should work! I'm trying to say:

> **If** the selected User has roles, then **loop through** and **show each** role

If this worked, I'd see Users on the left, and the roles for the selected user on the right:

[image: admin system]

The above doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure why! I get the error:

[image: error]

And line 343 is the return here:

```
self.SelectedUserHasRoles = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.selectedUser().roles().length > 0;
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shoud initialize your `selectedUser` in a `.done()` function chained to your `posts` calls

Comment: That was it! thanks @cl3m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that your `selectedUser` is null, as you initalize it with the first element of an empty array :

```
self.users = ko.observableArray([]); 
// => self.users[0] === null, and maybe you should use self.users()[0]
self.selectedUser = ko.observable(self.users[0]);
```

To avoid this issue, you could either add a loading boolean to indicate that your application is not done loading the users, or add a `Promise.all` call and then add your initalizing logic.

Using promises:

```
var promises = [$.post(...), $.post(...)]
Promise.all(promises).then(function(data) {
  // ... users and roles initalisation
  self.selectedUser(self.users()[0]);
})

// or via chained done method
$.post(...).done(function() {
  self.selectedUser(self.users()[0]);
})
```

or using a boolean logic (you may optimized this untested code):

```
self.loading = ko.observableArray(false)
self.isLoaded = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.loading().all(function(x) { return x }) // ES5 syntax
})

self.selectedUser = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  if (self.isLoaded()) return users()[0]
  return null
})
$.post('..roles', function() {
  // ...
  self.loading()[0] = true
})
$.post('..users', function() {
  // ...
  self.loading()[1] = true
})
```

and in your HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6" data-bind="if: $root.SelectedUserHasRoles()">
  <h4><i class="fa fa-shield" aria-hidden="true"></i> Roles</h4>
  <hr />
  <!-- ko if: !isLoaded() -->
  <span>Loading !</span>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko if: isLoaded() -->
  <div id="roles-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: $root.selectedUser().roles">
      <div class="role-token" data-bind="text: name"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```